# How do I find and count how many spaces of a particular type here?

Tags: java

I have these codes:

```
public class CentroImpl implements Centro {

//Atributos

private String nombre;
private String direccion;
private Integer numeroPlantas;
private Integer numeroSotanos;
public Set<Espacio> espacio;

//Constructor
public CentroImpl(String nombre, String direccion, Integer numeroPlantas, Integer numeroSotanos){
    checkPlantas(numeroPlantas);
    checkSotanos(numeroSotanos);
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.numeroPlantas = numeroPlantas;
    this.numeroSotanos = numeroSotanos;
    this.espacio = new TreeSet<Espacio>();
}

    @Override
public Set<Despacho> getDespachos() {

}
```

`getDespacho` is supposed to go through the list of 'Espacios' (places) in a building (centro) and tell me how many of them are `Despachos` (offices). As you can see in `Espacio class` there is a type defined.

```
public class EspacioImpl implements Espacio {

//Atributos
private TipoEspacio tipo;
private String nombre;
private Integer planta;
private Integer aforo;

//Constructores
public EspacioImpl(TipoEspacio tipo, String nombre, Integer planta, Integer aforo) {
    checkerAforo(aforo);
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.planta = planta;
    this.aforo = aforo;
    this.tipo = tipo;
}
```

But I have not learned yet how to access it, and I haven't been able to find anything understandable around. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is `TipoEspacio` an `enum`?

Comment: I'm thinking that there are some design flaws here. What does the `Espacio` interface look like?

Comment: There probably are @Daniel as this is one of my first programs to write. Pastebin of relevant files: http://pastebin.com/FJKEaseZ (Espacio is place, centro is building)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming Despacho extends Espacio and TipoEspacio is enum:

```
@Override
public Set<Despacho> getDespachos() {
    Set<Despacho>  despachos = new HashSet<Despacho>();
    for (Espacio e : espacio) {
        // Not sure, depends on the definition of TipoEspacio
        if (e.getTipo() == TipoEspacio.DESPACHO && e instanceof Despacho) {
          despachos.put((Despacho)e);
         }
    }
    return despachos;
}
```

Comment: I'm having problems with the put function that both of you put in your answers. Do I need to import something? Wouldn't add work betterç?

Comment: @BrickTop I updated my answer, it works only if Despacho extends Espacio. If not, please show us the Despacho (or DespachoImpl) source.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that you have a collection of `EspacioImpl`s called `espacios`, and that the `enum` name for a Despacho is `Despacho`. You then have to do something with `numDespachos` (like `return` it). This also assumes that `EspacioImpl` has a method called `getTipo`. You need this because the `tipo` member is `private`, and so it cannot be accessed outside the class without having a getter.

```
int numDespachos = 0;
for(EspacioImpl e : espacios)
{
    if(e.getTipo() == TipoEspacio.Despacho)
        ++numDespachos;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I actually wanted to return a list of the espacios that are despachos. I believe the answer above does that.